# Preventing duplicate REST calls

Tags: rest, security, duplicates

I'm creating an Android app that calls a PHP bases REST api methods for server side updates.

For example, to add reward points to customer, we can use:

http://example.com/rest/customer/add/1/20

Where 1 is customer id and 20 is reward points.

I was wondering how can I prevent duplicate calls to this URL. If for some reason, this URL is called twice, customer will get 20 more points. There is no such condition that customer cannot get more points on same day.

Also, how to prevent this URL to be executed anonymously?

Is OAuth 2.0 the best solution or there is something better?

Thanks

Comment: Is it intended that a given user can grant points to any other user?

Answer (score 0):

The REST/HTTP way of solving this would to make "conditional" `POST` request to a "reward points" resource.

The request to `POST` 20 points would look something like this:

```
POST /customer/1/points HTTP/1.1
If-Match: "0"
Host: ...

20
```

The `If-Match` header means that the `POST` should only complete if the resource you are trying to modify still has the state specified. In this case the 20 points will only be `POST`ed if the customer has `0` points. It can be thought of as an [optimistic locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control) mechanism.

Normally the server should respond with error code 412 (Precondition failed) if the If-Match precondition fails.

Note: that the points of the customer should be a resource.

To prevent unauthorized access to points, your server must implement some authentication mechanism. Simplest would be to respond with 401 (Unauthorized) if the user is not authenticated. If the user is authenticated, just does not have the right to update some points, return 403 (Forbidden).